# what is difference betwen REVERSE_INULL and FORWARD_NULL error in coverity scan(static code analysis)?

Tags: coverity, coverity-prevent

when i run coverity scan on python code (static code analysis), REVERSE_INULL and FORWARD_NULL error are detected. can anyone tell what is difference between REVERSE_INULL and FORWARD_NULL ? why these error are detected.

Answer (score 7):

`REVERSE_INULL` means that you have a dereference followed by a null-type check.

In pseudo code

```
x := null
...
x.deref
...
if x is null
    # handle null-type x
```

The fix would be to put the null-type check before the dereference.

`FORWARD_NULL` is simply where there is a path for a null-valued variable to be dereferenced. Another pseudo-code example

```
x := null
...
if x is null
    print warning
    # but x is still null

x.deref
```

Here you have to ensure that the null-ness is always handled.

So ultimately I'd say that `REVERSE_INULL` does the same null dereference checking as `FORWARD_NULL` but that it additionally detects a check after the dereference.

(standard disclaimer - I used to work for Synopsys, but not the division producing Coverity).